# Capturing 4:3 camera picture via android Camera2 API on camera with 16:9 sensor array

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to capture video with 4:3 aspect ratio from android fron-facing camera using Camera2 API (added in 5.0 version of android). It works correctly unless camera has 16:9 sensor array (as front-facing camera on Samsung Galaxy S5). In such case picture looks stretched as if 16:9 picture was being captured and squeezed into 4:3 surface provided by MediaRecorder.

According to documentation there shouldn't be any additional configuration needed as long as MediaRecorder's size has been set to one of sizes provided by [getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getOutputSizes(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)). Camera should automatically crop picture so it fits size of MediaRecorder's surface.

I tested also reversed situation - recording 16:9 video on camera with 4:3 sensor array (front-facing camera of Nexus-5). It works properly - picture is cropped to 16:9 aspect ratio.

I assume this is a bug in android API but would like to see whether there's something I miss here.

The simplest way to reproduce that problem is to use [camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample app provided by google with the following [change](https://github.com/mikosik/android-Camera2Basic/commit/c3cf9f3755d2844d3398fa6252f3e324eee63e92) that switches to using front-facing camera and 4:3 size for preview. It works correctly on Nexus-5 but provides stretched image on Samsung Galaxy S5. Below screenshot of camera2Basic app on Samsung Galaxy S5 (android 5.0).

[image]

Comment: did you figured out how to solve this problem? or nothing could be done in such case?

Comment: @Droidwala I haven't found any workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) use the built in cropping function to select a 4x3 region of the image if it is 16x9. That is, just crop to discard the "unnecessary" pixels on either side. This can be done just by adding a field/value to the CaptureRequest with [CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#SCALER_CROP_REGION).

The link explains it a little more, but all you really need is an if statement to check the ratio of the sensor and a little math to figure out the bounds of the region you want to select.

Comment: I tested with SCALER_CROP_REGION set to 4:3 and it didn't help.Picture is still stretched.

Comment: SCALER_CROP_REGION cannot do miracles, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42655935/192373

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid it by refere to android camera2 application source code.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/+/android-cts-5.1_r4/src/com/android/camera/one/v2/OneCameraZslImpl.java

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.